# How can I get the source of an iframe that only works on specified domains?

Tags: c#, html, iframe

So I'm trying to read the source of an url, let's say domain.xyz. No problem, I can simply get it work using HttpWebRequest.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

My problem is that it will return the page source, but without the source of the iframe inside this page. I only get something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://anotherdomain.xyz/frame_that_only_works_on_domain_xyz"></iframe>
```

I figured out that I can easily get the src of the iframe with WebBrowser, or basic string functions (the results are the same), and create another HttpWebRequest using the address. The problem is that if I view the full page (where the frame was inserted) in a browser (Chrome), i get the expected results. But if I copy the src to another tab, the contents are not the same. It says that the content I want to view is blocked because it's only allowed through domain.xyz.

So my final question is:
How can I simulate the request through a specified domain, or get the full, rendered page source?

Answer (score 0):

That's likely the `referer` property of the web request: typically a browser tells the web server where it found the link to the page it is requesting.

That means, when you create the web request for the iframe, you set the referer property of that request to the page containing the link.

If that doesn't work, cookies may be another option. I.e. you have to collect the cookies sent for the first request, and send them with the second request.

Comment: I tried to set the Referer to the original URL, and fill the CookieContainer with all of the cookies to the exact same, but the problem is still here... Somewhat the site that provides the frame are still know that it's a "crawler".

Comment: @BalázsVarga How does that response look like? Do you get an http error code, or a 200 response, and just the contents telling you that you must not do so? If it is in the content only, are there some scripts, images or the like embedded before that message appears? Did you also try to change the browser identifier for your requests?

Comment: I haven't changed browser identifier. The response is a valid html file, containing some css and a message that this content is not available to view directly.